# KDE 5.56 SDDM Login screen resolution on HiDPI FHD screen

Tags: kubuntu, kde, display-resolution, login-screen, sddm

[OP on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/amybg5/login_screen_on_hidpi_4k_screen/)

Hi,

I have a problem with Kubuntu 19.04 in my 13" FHD (1920x1080) laptop screen.
[image]
[image]
The login screen is too small as was the whole *Plasma KDE*.

I was able to re-scale the screen to 1.5 (150%) 
[image]
and now *Plasma KDE* looks great but the login screen still remains small (FHD scaled) though when I come back from *Suspend* mode the login screen do re-scales to 150%.

There is no file called `sddm.conf` under `/etc/`,  as written in the [project's github page](https://github.com/sddm/sddm#custom-dpi), in my OS `sddm.conf` located under `/etc/init`.

I have added the lines

```
[X11]
ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 144
```

At beginning of `/etc/init/sddm.conf` where 144 represents my base resolution in DPI as written in the X-Server information * 1.5[image]
but still it doesn't fix the login screen resolution scale.

Any suggestions will be gladly welcomed.

TNX

Comment: same problem here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225750/change-login-screen-resolutionn-sddm-on-kde-plasma-5-68) but no sddm.conf file anywhere... Any help would be welcome...

Answer (score 3):

In my Kubuntu 19.10, `/etc/init/sddm.conf` appears to contain script code instead of config variables. `/etc/sddm.conf` did exist, perhaps because this is based on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS that came with the XPS 13:

```console
$ cat /etc/sddm.conf 
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
Session=
User=

[General]
HaltCommand=
RebootCommand=

[Theme]
Current=ubuntu-theme
CursorTheme=breeze_cursors

[Users]
MaximumUid=60000
MinimumUid=1000

[X11]
ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 144
```

I added the `[X11]` section myself, rebooted, and now the initial login screen is more easily readable, as well as the session apps and lock screen. Even at Displays scale 1 i had to revert Fonts from 13 to 11 and lower. I'm running this QFHD at FHD to save battery and config stress:

[image: /etc/sddm.conf X11 dpi setting result]

PS: You can [calculate the proper PPI](https://www.sven.de/dpi/); QFHD in 13.3" is 331 and FHD on the same is 166.

Comment: Checking again, i also have `EnableHiDPI=true` under X11 and Wayland sections for some reason.

Comment: Just like you I have no sddm.conf file anywhere (see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225750/change-login-screen-resolutionn-sddm-on-kde-plasma-5-68), running kubuntu 20.04, which comes with kde 5.68